# Why is my url added to the enterprise_url_rewrite table but not core_url_rewrite?

Tags: magento-enterprise, indexing, url-rewrite, core, ee-1.13.0.1

Redirects in Magento have me utterly confused. Enterprise 1.13 has not helped the situation. My problem is this, I want to add a product link widget to the home page but newer products do not show up. I've traced the problem back to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link::getHref()`:

```
$urlRewriteResource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/url_rewrite');
$href = $urlRewriteResource->getRequestPathByIdPath($this->getData('id_path'), $store);
```

Now, the `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite` model uses the table `core_url_rewrite`. And my new products do not exist in that table! Weird, because they are Enabled, visible in Catalog, they have a url_key and I can navigate to the product page just fine. So they must exist in one of the other **Enterprise** tables. Which one?

```
core_url_rewrite -> Url Rewrites
enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite -> Relation between rewrites and categories
enterprise_catalog_product_rewrite -> Relation between rewrites and products
enterprise_url_rewrite -> URL Rewrite
enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect -> Permanent redirect
enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_rewrite -> Relation between rewrites and redirects
```

Yep, it exists in the `enterprise_url_rewrite` table ...

```
+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+------+-----------------------+-----+----------+----------+-------------+
| url_rewrite_id | request_path          | target_path                    | is_system | guid | identifier            | inc | value_id | store_id | entity_type |
+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+------+-----------------------+-----+----------+----------+-------------+
|       31282261 | product-1-working     | catalog/product/view/id/256037 |         1 | xyz  | product-1-working     |   1 |  9236282 |        0 |           3 |
|       31294573 | product-2-not-working | catalog/product/view/id/268697 |         1 | xyz  | product-2-not-working |   1 |  9610723 |        0 |           3 |
+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+------+-----------------------+-----+----------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but not in the `core_url_rewrite` table ...

```
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| url_rewrite_id | store_id | category_id | product_id | id_path        | request_path          | target_path                    | is_system | options | description |
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|        3512685 |        1 |        NULL |     256037 | product/256037 | product-1-working.htm | catalog/product/view/id/256037 |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.34 sec)
```

Next I tried reindexing the url indexes (and if someone could explain the difference between these I'd appreciate it)

```
$ php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url_product,url_redirect
Product URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
URL Redirects index was rebuilt successfully
```

Nope, still nothing. What do I have to do to get products in the `core_url_rewrite` table, other than by creating them manually myself?

Comment: In short, this is how EE works, in 1.13 it uses enterprise_ tables, in CE 1.8 uses core_rewrite table, just have to use the appropriate one for the version you work on

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov So how/why does anything get written to the core_ table?

Comment: If you change `$urlRewriteResource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/url_rewrite');` to `$urlRewriteResource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('enterprise/url_rewrite');` does it work then? It may just be an oversight in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link`.

Comment: @nachito you can write to core_url_rewrite if you really want, but only for your needs, EE 1.13 is not using it

Answer (score 6):

In Magento Enterprise the is a new module for storing url rewrite `Enterprise_UrlRewrite`. This module contains new tables for storing the rewrites, some layout files for the admin section, a new admin html controller and a new url matcher to name but a few items.

To understand when the enterprise system uses the new tables for saving rewrites we can first look into the controller `Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Adminhtml_UrlrewriteController`, here we find the function `_getRedirect` which is used to to load the current redirect being worked on and returns a model of type `Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Redirect`.

If we then look into the config.xml for `Enterprise_UrlRewrite` you can see that it has it's own table information stored so that when the model is being used it does not use the standard community tables.

```
<models>
    <enterprise_urlrewrite>
        <class>Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>enterprise_urlrewrite_resource</resourceModel>
    </enterprise_urlrewrite>
    <enterprise_urlrewrite_resource>
        <class>Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <url_rewrite>
                <table>enterprise_url_rewrite</table>
            </url_rewrite>
            <redirect>
                <table>enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect</table>
            </redirect>
            <redirect_rewrite>
                <table>enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_rewrite</table>
            </redirect_rewrite>
        </entities>
    </enterprise_urlrewrite_resource>
</models>
```

The structure of these new tables, is in my opinion vast improvement of the community editions single table, as the category and product information is moved into separate tables and also the redirect information is also separated.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1.13 EE, like you already found out in the database, all rewrites, redirects etc. are moved from core to enterprise related tables.

You can find the needed files in the `Enterprise_UrlRewrite` module. The `Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Url_Rewrite` class contains a method to load rewrites by requestPath. The classgroup string for the getModel factory is `enterprise_urlrewrite/url_rewrite`.

Ignore the core_url_rewrite table, it's only for CE.