# Enterprise Catalog Routing & Rewrites

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog, url-rewrite, routing

I'm working on a Magento Enterprise site and I'm having an issue figuring out how catalog routing and rewrites work in EE 1.14.1.0.

In Magento CE, the `core_url_rewrite` table is used to transform a product's URL key into an MVC+ID routing path. You'll find entries in that table like this:

```
id_path: product/123
request_path: my-url-key.html
target_path: catalog/product/view/id/123

id_path: product/123/10
request_path: my-category/my-url-key.html
target_path: catalog/product/view/id/123/category/10
```

The problem is that at some point in this site's history, they upgraded to a sufficiently new version of Magento where this is no longer used for catalog rewrites. Any product with a sufficently high enough ID doesn't appear in this table. Yet I can still go to `example.com/my-url-key.html` or `example.com/my-category/my-url-key.html` to find my products.

Can someone enlighten me as to how EE 1.14.1.0 is doing rewrites now? I've searched the code base for anything that `extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router` in it, trying to find if maybe `Mage_Catalog` or `Enterprise_Catalog` has a new router, but I can't find one.

Comment: @alan-storm Save me!

Comment: 1.13.x saw the changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992525/how-does-the-new-magento1-13-ee-url-rewrites-work-how-do-the-new-database-table

Comment: @TylerV. does this cover it? http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/18275/158